# Origin Point is rotating with the camera

Tags: modeling, camera, origin

I just have a problem with origin point, I searched for 4 days now and this seems to be the only place where people could help.

I cant move objects properly because the axes are not static, they move with camera. Its like the Origin Point itself is rotating with the camera.

Is there a way to reset this back to normal?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Could you add a screenshot of your 3D view showing your transform manipulator settings?

Comment: thank you for help,but I figured it out. Turns out I was stupid and didn´t notice the button next to transformations (the one that usually says Global)